# Why are my 2 separate elements being change by 1 styling in my css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have my nav bar here

html

```
<div class="nav">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
            <a href="fridge.html"><li>Refrigerators</li></a>
            <a href="stove.html"><li>Stoves</li></a>
            <a href="dishwasher.html"><li>Dishwashers</li></a>
            <a href="hvac.html"><li>HVAC</li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Then I have my product items here

html

```
<div class="products"> 
    <a href="fridge.html"><figure class="fridge">
        <img src="imgs/fridge.jpeg" alt="Refrigerators">
        <figcaption>Refrigerators</figcaption>
    </figure></a>
</div>
```

I only inserted 1 but there are 4 of these total. Im doing the css for a media query to show on screen size of max width 480px. My nav bar is located at the top of the layout and my products are located at the bottom. My nav bar is set to inline and for the media query i'm changing the products div from display grid/columns to flex/flex direction column. The problem I'm having is that when I change the products to flex column the css is also changing the nav bar to a row layout and I have no idea why this is happening. These 2 separate divs don't have any of the same class names or anything other than they both have  tags but im not targeting the  tag.

This is the css that changes it

css

```
.products {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   margin-top: 0px
}
```

This is my nav bar css

css

```
.nav ul li, a {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    right: -80px;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: the hyperlinks should be children of the `li` elements rather than parents to them as they are now.

Comment: Indeed, your HTML is invalid, `ul` can only have `li` as children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apply a double style with this selector

```
.nav ul li, a { }
```

You need `.nav ul li a { }` no ?

And better use `<li><a></a></li>`

Comment: Quite likely but that 2nd rule would not follow the invalid markup the OP has